# Share PersistentVolumeClaims between pods/deployments on Okteto

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims, okteto

With Okteto Cloud, in order to let different pods/deployments access a shared PersistentVolumeClaim, I tried setting the PersistentVolumeClaim's `accessModes` to `"ReadWriteMany"`:

```
{
    "kind": "PersistentVolumeClaim",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "pv-claim-cpdownloads"
    },
    "spec": {
        "accessModes": [
            "ReadWriteMany"
        ],
        "resources": {
            "requests": {
                "storage": "10Gi"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Applying my deployment with `kubectl` succeeds, but the deployment itself times out on the okteto web UI, with the error:

```
pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 55 times)
```

---

Now, the same PersistentVolumeClaim with `accessModes` set to `"ReadWriteOnce"` deploys just fine.

**Is the accessMode `"ReadWriteMany"` disallowed on Okteto Cloud ?**

**If it is, how could I get several pods/deployments to access the same volume data ?**

For precisions, in my case I think I technically only need one pod to write to the volume and the other one to read from it.

My use case is to have one container save files to a folder, and another container watches changes and loads files from that same folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okteo Cloud only supports the "ReadWriteOnce" access mode.
If you share the volume between pods/deployments they will all go to the same node, which is equivalent to have a single reader/writer. But it is not a recommended practice.

What is your use case? why do you need to share volumes?

Comment: Added a bit more on what my use case is (or well, "was", since my goal was to install couchpotato + transmission + jellyfin on a server, and Ramiro just confirmed what I suspected, that bittorrent's not allowed on Okteto)
In that setup transmission would have downloaded files to a folder, and Jellyfin would have served them in a web UI.

Comment: "ReadWriteOnce" should be ok then. Another option is to define both containers in the same deployment/pod, and share an "EmptyDir" volume between them.

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know EmptyDir volumes yet so I'll read a bit about that